# Java Chromium jcef how to drop after drag

Tags: browser, plugins, chromium-embedded

i use the idea jcef to create browser.i want to drag something in the browser into idea . i hope here will provide method like droptarget.but icannot find.CefDragHandler only has onDragEnter.

onDragEnter